# Calculating the Barrier Between Rotamers

Tags: organic-chemistry, computational-chemistry, physical-organic-chemistry

There are two stable conformations of a medium-sized organic molecule roughly 5 kcal/mol apart in ground state energies. One is probably the global minimum conformer identified through a conformer search— the other is the reactive conformer that would eventually lead to product formation. Both have been optimized with DFT. Say I want to calculate the barrier to accessing the higher energy, reactive conformer, how would I do that? I suspect that although the higher energy conformation is thermodynamically feasible, perhaps it is not kinetically accessible. I know from basic conformational analysis that these barriers can be quantified from the energetic cost of rotating about dihedral angles, however I can’t think of any systematic way to do this for a larger system. Any ideas? Or am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which program you are using, there will be a way to calculate the potential energy surface (PES) by scanning along a particular coordinate (bond length, angle or dihedral). For instance, if you wanted to look at the PES of the stretch between hydrogen and oxygen in water, you can tell a program to calculate a single point energy (SPE) when the O–H bond length is 0.7 Å, then calculate a further 10 SPEs after increasing the bond length by 0.01 Å per scan step (for example). This is called a 'rigid scan'.

While you can make sure that the only change in geometry is the coordinate you are scanning, programs will generally also allow you to alter the coordinate and, at the same time, optimise the geometry of the rest of the molecule to compensate for the change in scanned coordinate. This is called a 'relaxed scan'.

If you go to the documentation of the program you are using and search for 'scan' you should be able to find it. (Relaxed scans are generally run through the geometry optimisation procedure, so you might have to look there if you want to run a relaxed scan.) All you need to do is specify the coordinate you want to scan across, tell the program how many scan points you want, and work out your start and end points.

Good luck!